# Why is a primitive defined on an open set?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read the following definition for a primitive in Stein and Shakarchi. I have a couple of questions:

Suppose $f$ is a function on the open set $\Omega.$ A primitive for $f$ on $\Omega$ is a function $F$ that is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and such that $F'(z) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \Omega.$

1. Is there any reason why we need $\Omega$ to be an open set? Can't we define a primitive on an arbitrary set? Maybe it is that if $f$ has a primitive at a point $z$ then it has a primitive for an open set containing $z?$
2. Is the part "a function $F$ that is holomorphic on $\Omega$" redundant? Isn't this condition implied with $F'(z) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \Omega?$

Comment: Derivative at a point can only be defined if the function is defined in a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote ?

Comment: I think the OP should have raised this question when he first studied derivative of a real valued function of  a real variable. There is nothing special here to discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Openness is required for derivatives to make sense.
2. Holomorphic is required for complex derivative to exist (complex differentiability is much more restrictive than differentiability on $\Bbb R^2$).

Comment: Hmm...But isn't saying $F'(z) = f(z)$ basically saying that $F$ is holomorphic at $z$ because the derivative, $f(z),$ exists? I was wondering if that phrase added anything more than just saying $F'(z) = f(z)$ at all $z \in \Omega.$

Comment: I guess it doesn't give any additional information. That being said, being clear is a good thing and worth a slight redundancy. On the other hand, some authors might think that you aren't _allowed_ to write "$F'(z)$" unless you've already established that $F$ is holomorphic.